# Load modules conditionally Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wrote a main python module that need load a file parser to work, initially I was a only one text parser module, but I need add more parsers for different cases.
parser_class1.py
parser_class2.py
parser_class3.py

Only one is required for every running instance, then I'm thinking load it by command line:

```
mmain.py -p parser_class1
```

With this purpose I wrote this code in order to select the parser to load when the main module will be called:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
aparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
aparser.add_argument('-p',
            action='store',
            dest='module',
            help='-p module to import')
results = aparser.parse_args()

if not results.module:
    aparser.error('Error! no module')
try:
    exec("import %s" %(results.module))
    print '%s imported done!'%(results.module)
except ImportError, e:
    print e
```

But, I was reading that this way is dangerous, maybe no stardard..

Then, is this approach ok? or I must find another way to do it?
Why?
Thanks, any comment are welcome.

Comment: what about `__import__()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how to use `__import__()`

```
allowed_modules = ['os', 're', 'your_module', 'parser_class1.py', 'parser_class2.py']

if not results.module:
    aparser.error('Error! no module')
try:
    if results.module in allowed_modules:
        module = __import__(results.module)
        print '%s imported as "module"'%(results.module)
    else:
        print 'hey what are you trying to do?'
except ImportError, e:
    print e

module.your_function(your_data)
```

**`EVAL` vs `__IMPORT__()`**

using `eval` allows the user to run any code on your computer. Don't do that. `__import__()` only allows the user to load modules, apparently not allowing user to run arbitrary code. But it's only apparently safer.

The proposed function, without `allowed_modules` is still risky since it can allow to load an arbitrary model that may have some malicious code running on when loaded. Potentially the attacker can load a file somewhere (a shared folder, a ftp folder, a upload folder managed by your webserver ...) and call it using your argument.

**WHITELISTS**

Using `allowed_modules` mitigates the problem but do not solve it completely: to hardening even more you still have to check if the attacker wrote a "os.py", "re.py", "your_module.py", "parser_class1.py" into your script folder,  since python first searches module there ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)).

Eventually you may compare parser_class*.py code against a list of hashes, like [sha1sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum) does.

**FINAL REMARKS**: At the real end, if user has write access to your script folder you cannot ensure an absolutely safe code.

Comment: btw, you have a typo in your help argument, it says "-i" instead of "-p"

Answer (score 5):

You could actually just execute the `import` statement inside a conditional block:

```
if x:
    import module1a as module1
else:
    import module1b as module1
```

You can account for various whitelisted module imports in different ways using this, but effectively the idea is to pre-program the imports, and then essentially use a GOTO to make the proper imports... If you do want to just let the user import any arbitrary argument, then the `__import__` function would be the way to go, rather than `eval`.

**Update:**

As @thedox mentioned in the comment, the `as module1` section is the idiomatic way for loading similar APIs with different underlying code. 
In the case where you intend to do completely different things with entirely different APIs, that's not the pattern to follow.
A more reasonable pattern in this case would be to include the code related to a particular import with that import statement:

```
if ...:
    import module1
    # do some stuff with module1 ...

else:
    import module2
    # do some stuff with module2 ...
```

As for *security*, if you allow the user to cause an import of some arbitrary code-set (e.g. their own module, perhaps?), it's not much different than using `eval` on user-input. It's essentially the same vulnerability: the user can get your program to execute their own code.

I don't think there's a truly safe manner to let the user import *arbitrary* modules, at all. The exception here is if they have no access to the file-system, and therefore cannot create new code to be imported, in which case you're basically back to the whitelist case, and may as well implement an explicit whitelist to prevent future-vulnerabilities if/when at some point in the future the user does gain file-system access.

Comment: This is an idiomatic way of loading modules if they have the same API but different guts, like os.path

Comment: I agree that it's idiomatic when you're checking to see if the module is available, if you need to load one of many modules depending on the value of a runtime input... Some patterns are better for this case than others.

Comment: @theodox and marr75: agreed. I think the question is concentrated more on whether there is a safe to import based on user input. But the moment you let the user execute _arbitrary_ imports, they could introduce their own code anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You should think of all of the possible modules you may import for that parsing function and then use a case statement or dictionary to load the correct one. For example:

```
import parser_class1, parser_class2, parser_class3

parser_map = {
    'class1': parser_class1,
    'class2': parser_class2,
    'class3': parser_class3,
}

if not args.module:
    #report error
    parser = None
else:
    parser = parser_map[args.module]
#perform work with parser
```

If loading any of the parser_classN modules in this example is expensive, you can define lambdas or functions that return that module (i.e. `def get_class1(): import parser_class1; return parser_class1`) and alter the line to be `parser = parser_map[args.module]()`

The `exec` option could be very dangerous because you're executing unvalidated user input. Imagine if your user did something like -

```
mmain.py -p "parser_class1; some_function_or_code_that_is_malicious()"
```

Comment: are there some penalty having all modules imported?

Comment: Whatever memory and processing resources are needed to load each of your modules. It seems (in your example) like you're loading pretty simple parser classes so I would suspect that you find no practical difference. If you prefer you can use the suggestion of mapping to a callable function that returns the parser instead, eliminating unnecessary module loading.